# SuiteScript Render PDF With multiple body in <pdf> label and the <totalPageNumber> shows 0 while the last body works good

Tags: pdf, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

In SuiteCloud Development Framework, Anyone caught in one situation that when you want Multiple kinds of PDFs in one file,
And the page Number is independent for each body.

I tried to put multiple  into one  label, It works good, But one thing is quite Confused, It's'  label was out of working except for the last body.

Hereby I wanna ask for some help that can help figure out this  problem,
Or can count the total page Number in another way.

Thank you in advance for any help/ advice.
Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you are putting together the PDF xml code but one thing you can do is that you can use the `pdfset` tag to put multiple documents into one and within `pdfset` tag you can use separate `pdf` tag for each of your documents.
Please take a look at below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><!DOCTYPE pdf PUBLIC "-//big.faceless.org//report" "report-1.1.dtd">
<pdfset>
    <!-- PDF 1 -->
    <pdf>
        <body height='11.69in' width='8.27in'>
            <p>Hello World Once!</p>
            <table width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td align="right">Page <pagenumber/>/<totalpages/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </body>
    </pdf>
    <!-- PDF 2 -->
    <pdf>
        <body height='11.69in' width='8.27in'>
            <p>Hello World Twice!</p>
            <table width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td align="right">Page <pagenumber/>/<totalpages/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <pbr/>
            <p>Hello World Again!</p>
        </body>
    </pdf>
    <!-- PDF 3 -->
    <pdf>
        <body height='11.69in' width='8.27in'>
            <p>Hello World Thrice!</p>
            <table width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td align="right">Page <pagenumber/>/<totalpages/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <pbr/>
            <p>Hello World Again!</p>
        </body>
    </pdf>
</pdfset>
```

This way total page number will not be 0 and independent for each of your PDFs.

Comment: Thank you for your help, It does help me out, not directly.
When I Add 
`<head>
  <meta name="title" value="My First Document"/>
</head>`
Among <pdf> and <body> label, It works in NetSuite PDF Engine.

Thank you again And Regards.